# What is this device on the nose of an MD-11?

Tags: feature-identification, md-11

In the following photo there is some sort of cover or opening (for an optical device I assume) on the nose cone.

What is this and what is the system behind it?

[image: MD-11]

([link to source](https://www.airplane-pictures.net/photo/1172932/n527fe-fedex-federal-express-mcdonnell-douglas-md-11f/))

Comment: For a while I thought it was a very muddy plane (I have no idea how it would have gotten muddy) poorly photoshopped with... something else. It took a while to realize that was on the deicing pad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enhanced flight vision system](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=764309)

[or a different angle](https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/624364-fedex-special-toy.html)

[wiki says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_flight_vision_system)

> An Enhanced flight vision system (EFVS, sometimes EVS) is an airborne system which provides an image of the scene and displays it to the pilot, in order to provide an image in which the scene and objects in it can be better detected.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!